# Combinatorics with colored balls

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, combinatorics

Seven blue and four red balls are to be arranged in order. How many ways can this be done if

(1) The blue balls are distinguishable (e.g. numbered) as are the red balls.

(2) Blue balls are distinguishable, but the red balls are identical.

(3) The balls of each color are indistinguishable.

My attempt at solution for (3) is C(11,7). I believe this to be correct. For (1), I think the answer is 11! but I'm not really sure. And I'm stuck on how to approach (2). Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job for the first and third part.

For the second part. For any arrangement in part $1$ that is distinguishable, we erase the numbers of the red balls. That is each configuration is counted $4!$ times. To avoid double counting, we divided the answer in the first part by that. That is we have $$\frac{11!}{4!}.$$

An alternative view is we first choose the spot for the red ball and then arrange the blue balls. Hence
$$\binom{11}{4}\cdot 7!=\frac{11!}{4!}$$